# Expected a value of type "imageProvider<object>",but got one of type'_HashSet<AssetImage>'>'

Tags: flutter

> I want to make dynamic coursel to achive this im using for loop ad taking length of variable

```
      height: 200.0,
      child: new Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
//Start problem Area
        images: [
          for (int i = 0; i < widget.eoprod_slider.length; i++)
            {AssetImage(widget.eoprod_slider[i])}
        ],//End Problem Area
        autoplay: false,
        dotSize: 4.0,
        indicatorBgPadding: 2.0,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map them into a list and pass it as it is:

```
      height: 200.0,
      child: new Carousel(
        boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
        //Start problem Area
        images: widget.eoprod_slider.map((e)=>AssetImage(e)).toList(),
        //End Problem Area
        autoplay: false,
        animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        dotSize: 4.0,
        indicatorBgPadding: 2.0,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it works | but i want to know via for loop same thing isn't possible

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer, thanks. It is possible using a for loop, but you would have to create the list outside your build method. Syntax issues l.